# I'm querying a table but I need the output in different columns

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by, count, conditional-aggregation

Let's say I have a table, sample below

```
Member ID  | Hotel ID  | Country | 
----------- ----------- ----------
100         ZZA         Country 1
101         ZZA         Country 2
102         ZZB         Country 2
103         ZZC         Country 3
201         XXD         Country 4
202         XXE         Country 1
203         AAB         Country 1
```

I need to output the count of members in different countries based on different rules:

- Rule 1: Count of members in Countries with members with Hotel ID starting in XX or AA.
- Rule 2: Count of members in Countries with members with Member ID starting with 10.

I can write 2 different queries to have an output like this:

```
Rule 1
Country  |  Member Count
--------- ----------
Country 4  1
Country 1  2
```

```
Rule 2
Country  |  Member Count
--------- ----------
Country 2  2
Country 1  1
Country 3  1
```

Is there a way to have 1 query and 1 output in different column? Like this:

```
Country | Rule 1 | Rule 2
-------- -------- --------
Country 1    2       1   
Country 2    0       2
Country 3    0       1 
Country 4    1       0
```

I'm using DB Browser for SQLite where I created a table and imported the CSV file I'm working on. I know I can use pivot tables for this but it's too slow.

Comment: just use "right outer join" ?

Comment: I have 2 separate queries for 1 table. I want to 1 query combining the 2 outputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group by country and use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT Country,
       SUM(HotelID LIKE 'XX%' OR HotelID LIKE 'AA%') Rule1,
       SUM(MemberID LIKE '10%') Rule2
FROM tablename
GROUP BY Country;
```

Or with `SUBSTR()` instead of `LIKE`:

```
SELECT Country,
       SUM(SUBSTR(HotelID, 1, 2) IN ('XX', 'AA')) Rule1,
       SUM(SUBSTR(MemberID, 1, 2) = '10') Rule2
FROM tablename
GROUP BY Country;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=8c9797f0151e1d22bd1d852ee9c11e62).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a single query of the form

```
select Country,
    count(case when <rule1> then 1 end) rule1,
    count(case when <rule2> then 1 end) rule2
from tbl
where (<rule1>) or (<rule2>)
group by Country
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=2730f5b2bd0de170368e02a90bc3d71b)

Comment: You may accept the answer to show it works.

Comment: Follow up question, supposed I have another table with the same rules and countries but contains data from another region, how do I combine these 2? Thank you!

Comment: @bixby . . . New questions should be asked as questions, not comments.

Comment: @bixby, .. You' d better ask another question and show what the desired output is like